# How to link to external c library with ruby's mkmf?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mkmf

I have the following files in this directory:

```
~/test/lib/liblost.dylib
~/test/include/lost.h
```

I am trying to let my rubygem determine if the above library exists by doing the following in irb:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :008 > dir_config('','~/test')
 => ["~/test/include", "~/test/lib"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :009 > have_library('lost')
checking for main() in -llost... no
 => false
```

Can someone please explain why this isn't working?

Comment: Are you sure `liblost.dylib` is a shared library? What does `file liblost.dylib` show?

Comment: liblost.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it's due to using `~` to specify the home directory. The shell only expands `~` to the path of your home directory if it is the first character of a word. When `mkmf` constructs the command line to call the compiler to check for the existence of the library it specifies the directory to call using the `-L` option, and it ends up looking like `-L~/test/lib`, and so isn't expanded. You should be able to see this in the `mkmf.log` file.

The fix is to avoid the `~` character in the directory path, or ensure it gets expanded before it gets used in the call to the compiler.

You could do this by changing `dir_config('','~/test')` to:

```
dir_config('', File.expand_path('~/test'))
```